# If statement for all values in list python

Tags: list, python-2.7, if-statement, for-loop

I wonder how to get if statements for all list indexes

```
#a = int(input("a "))
a = [10,10,10]
#b = int(input("b "))
b = [100,10,10]
#c = int(input("c "))
c = [10,10,10]
#d = int(input("d "))
d = [100,10,10]

for itema in a:
    print itema
for itemb in b:
    print itemb
for itemc in c:
    print itemc
for itemd in d:
    print itemd

if itema>=itemd:
    print "make math equation nr.1"
elif itemb<itemd:
    print "make math equation nr.2"
```

I try to check my condition through all elements in list and get list with results. Which technics should I use ?

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
for itema, itemb, itemd in zip(a, b, d):
    if itema > itemd:
        print('eq 1')
    elif itemb < itemd:
        print('eq. 2')
```